# The Ikṣvākus in the Vedas

Tags: vedas, ramayana, rama

In the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa , We have characters who belong to Vedic Dynasties. **Goddess Sītā** is from the **Videha** Empire and is the daughter of King **Janaka Vaideha** who is mentioned in the Brāhmaṇas and Upaniṣads as a performer of Yajñas and as a great philosopher king **(Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa , Jaiminīya Brāhmaṇa and Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad)**

**Kaikeyī** is from the **Kekaya** Kingdom and is the daughter of **Aśvapati Kaikeya** who is also mentioned in the Vedas **( Śatapatha Brāhmaṇa and Chhāndogya Upaniṣad)**. We also know that the Kaikeyas , Like the Madrakas were descendants of the **Ṛgvedic Anu Tribe.**

I want to know if the **Ikṣvāku Vamśa** of **Lord Rāma** is mentioned in any text by name in the Vedas. Of course Ikṣvāku kings like **Māndhātṛ** are mentioned but what proof do we have from the Śruti that they were **Aikṣvākas**. Can anyone please provide me with atleast 4-5
references from the Vedic Texts that mention the **Ikṣvākus**.

Thanks

**Jaya Śrī Rāma**

[image]